# Make alias script failing

Tags: macos, path, applescript, alias

Infrequent AppleScript user here, so this may be something incredibly basic, but I can't seem to make an extremely simple script to create a new alias file work.  Here's the script in its entirety:

```
set source_file to "/path/to/test.txt"
set alias_file to "/path/to/test.txt alias"
tell application "Finder" to make new alias at alias_file to source_file
```

I've tried it with and without the "new".  I've tried it with "POSIX file" in front of the file names and with "as POSIX file" as a coercion after the file names.  I've tried with "at * to *" and "to * at *".  Just in case the destination needed to be a containing folder I've tried that.  Absolutely all variations produce the same error message:

```
execution error: Finder got an error: AppleEvent handler failed. (-10000)
```

which doesn't tell me a lot.

I've obviously replaced the actual file paths with "/path/to/" here, but I can assure that `ls /path/to/test.txt` confirms the source path is valid, and `ls "/path/to/test.txt alias"` confirms the target path does not exist.

In case it matters, I'm running Mac OS X 10.11.5.  The Finder.sdef entry for make sure looks like it should do what I want:

> ```
> make v : Make a new element   make
>
> new type : the class of the new element
>
> at location specifier : the location at which to insert the element
>
> [to specifier] : when creating an alias file, the original
>   item to create an alias to or when creating a file viewer window,
>   the target of the window
>
> [with properties record] : the initial values for the properties of
>   the element → specifier : to the new object(s)
> ```

What I really want to do is run this with osascript from the command line and what I really, really want to do is invoke the osascript one-liner from Python, so the file paths will be inline, rather than in variables.  But I moved first to the command line and then to the script editor since I couldn't get it to work, and every single method of invoking this code snippet produces the same error message.  So hopefully when/if I get a script to work I'll be able to invoke equivalent code from osascript from Python. :}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were definitely on the right track with using `POSIX file` since [AppleScript represents file paths differently than POSIX does](http://www.satimage.fr/software/en/smile/external_codes/file_paths.html) (in essence, colons instead of forward slashes).

You could manually translate all the paths into AppleScript paths, but casting them is, I think, a better solution in order to keep the file paths readable (and make it clear to you reading the source code that they are indeed file paths).

However, the problem with `POSIX file` is that it returns a file reference instead of the text path that the `make new alias` command is looking for. To resolve this, all you have to do is cast the returned file reference as `text` to make `alias` happy:

```
set source_file to (POSIX file "/path/to/test.txt") as text
set alias_file to (POSIX file "/path/to/test.txt alias") as text
tell application "Finder" to make new alias at alias_file to source_file
```

There's one more problem, though: the `make new alias at x to y` command expects `y` to be a path to a file and `x` to be a path to a directory where the alias should be placed, but you're passing a path to a file for both `x` and `y`. The destination ("at") path should just be `/path/to/` – the `make new alias` command will automatically name the alias `{original filename} alias`. So, in summation:

```
set source_file to (POSIX file "/path/to/test.txt") as text
set alias_dir to (POSIX file "/path/to/") as text
tell application "Finder" to make new alias at alias_dir to source_file
```

That may have been a little long-winded, but I hope it helps!

Comment: @larryy Great! Glad I could help.

Comment: Corrections: 1. Colon-separated HFS paths are an old pre-OSX hangover. AS supports those for backwards compatibility (and cos AS devs are lazy), and also supports standard POSIX paths. 2. Finder expects _object specifiers_ (e.g. `file "test.txt" of folder "Documents" of home`), but will in _most_ use cases accept HFS path strings (Finder is also an old pre-OSX hangover) or `alias`/`POSIX file` specifiers and convert them; `get` and `set` are exceptions. 3. HFS paths are fundamentally flawed—they cannot distinguish between identically named volumes—so always use POSIX paths wherever possible.

Comment: 4. As you say, the `make` command's `at` parameter requires a reference to the folder object in which the new object will be created. If you wish to give the new alias object a specific name, use the `with parameter`. Example: `tell application "Finder" to make new alias at (POSIX file "/Users/jsmith/Desktop") to (POSIX file "/Users/jsmith/Documents") with properties {name:"My Docs"}`

Comment: Actually the proper AppleScript class of a Finder alias is `alias file`.

Comment: @vadian: You're right, that should really read `make new alias file at...`. (As it happens, Finder is uncommonly forgiving about such typos and is willing to accept `alias` as a synonym in this particular context. OTOH, there are other situations where it _won't_ treat them as interchangeable - at which point such sloppiness _will_ catch you out - so being 100% precise and 100% accurate on all occasions is still a very good habit to get into.)

Comment: Is there a way to make a new alias as administrator?  I have tried using 'with administrator privileges' but Applescript wont allow me to do that.